# Как сделать смену картинки раз в неделю?

Tags: javascript, html

Создаю сайт на конструкторе Tilda, где есть возможность добавить скрипт в формате HTML, JavaScript. Мне необходимо чтоб в главном блоке была картинка внизу прилагаю пример кода который использовал в этом конструкторе для другой задачи, возможно будет полезен. У каждого блока есть айди, если я создам блок для Изображения и Блок в котором будет работать скрипт. Прилагаю скрины - бек http://prntscr.com/kglk3p фронт http://prntscr.com/kglkiw

Нужно чтоб картинка менялась каждый понедельник. Всего 4 картинки и в следующем месяце снова начинался этот цикл.

(пример скрипта который работает на добавление формы)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//Добавляем класс к ZeroBlock 
$("#rec61541110").addClass("zerosformoy"); 
//Добавляем класс к форме
$("#rec61544759").addClass("formavzero");    

//клонируем нашу форму в ZeroBlock
$(".formavzero").appendTo(".zeroformvert");

//Скрывает табличку с ошибкой заполнения
$(".formavzero .t-form__errorbox-bottom").hide();
$(".formavzero .t-form__errorbox-middle").hide();
//Скрывает надписи об ошибке заполнения
$(".formavzero .t-input-error").hide();
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
/*Задаём цвет и отступы таблички об успешной отправке данных */    
   .formavzero .t-form__successbox{
        background:#4bbf15 !important;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }    
/*Высота полей ввода */    
    .formavzero input{
    height: 40px !important;
    }
/*Отступ между полями */     
    .formavzero .t-input-group{
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    }
/*Задаём высоту и плавный переход для кнопки в Zero */
    .formavzero .t-submit{
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 100%;
    }  
/*Задаём отступ текста под формой */
    .formavzero .t-form__bottom-text{
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    }      
     /*Размер шрифта политики*/
    .formavzero .t678__form-bottom-text{
    font-size: 10px !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    }      
    /*Размер шрифта подписи полей ввода*/
    .formavzero .t-input-subtitle{
        color:#ffffff;
        opacity: 0.90 !important;
        font-size:16px !important;
    }
    /*Ширина выбора полей ввода Дата и Время*/
    .t39 .t-inputtime, .t678 .t-datepicker__wrapper {
        max-width: none !important;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Наверное надо запрашивать разные картинки в зависимости от клиентского времени? Разве нет?

Comment: Можно это реализовать, используя PHP. Там это делается максимально просто.